Meaning of 靈活運用詩文名句，增添文采。
靈活運用詩文名句，增添文采。
From the dictionary, 文采 means:

Words/sentence/phrase

Writing talent


Common sense tells me it's 2, but I'm not sure because by 1 it could also mean increasing word count. Thanks for the help.

Your common sense is spot on, It is "2"

"Writing talent" refers to the ability of a writer to write well. It makes 增添文采 sound like "improving one's writing skills". Couldn't "文采" also refer directly to the "style/flair/elegance" of a piece of writing? If so, 增添文采 would mean something like "adding flair", "using more elegant language". I believe that's what's intended here, which makes "talent" a poor translation in this case.

贴切的引语和珠玑般的诗句为他的演说词增添文采。
Apt citations and poetic gems adorn his speeches.
靈活運用詩文名句，增添文采。
Flexible use of poetry, literature and quotations make for graceful prose.


靈活運用詩文名句，增添文采。


From the dictionary, 文采 means:



Words/sentence/phrase




Writing talent


靈活運用詩文名句, 增添文采 - Flexible use of famous poems and verses, increases brilliance/glamorous in (one's) "writings/literary works".
Note, "增添文采" can also be expanded as "增添文章光采 or 增添文筆风采".
汉典/百度百科 - 文采 (with edits)
- 本指文章具有错杂艳丽的色彩，现多指文章中表现出来的典雅艳丽和令人赏心悦目的色彩和风格。一般来说，一篇文章的文采(brilliance/glamorous)主要通过其优美的语言(language)表现出来。因此，适当地修饰语言(運用詩文名句)是可以达到增加文采的目的的。
